# cannot change mariadb datadir since debian 9

Tags: mariadb, debian-stretch

I've done this 1000 times on debian 8 but with no success since I tried on debian 9.

I would like to change the default datadir for mariadb, here is the process from a virgin debian 9 VM:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client
service mysql stop
rsync -av /var/lib/mysql /home/
vi /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

grep -r datadir /etc/mysql/
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:datadir     = /home/mysql   

[11:29:32]root@deb9: ~ # ls -la /home/mysql/
drwxr-xr-x 4 mysql mysql     4096 Sep  7 11:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root      4096 Sep  7 11:25 ..
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql    16384 Sep  7 11:25 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql       52 Sep  7 11:25 aria_log_control
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root         0 Sep  7 11:25 debian-10.1.flag
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 12582912 Sep  7 11:25 ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 50331648 Sep  7 11:25 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 50331648 Sep  7 11:25 ib_logfile1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        0 Sep  7 11:25 multi-master.info
drwx------ 2 mysql root      4096 Sep  7 11:25 mysql
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql     4096 Sep  7 11:25 performance_schema

service mysql start


Sep  7 09:27:44 debian systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Sep  7 09:27:44 debian mysqld[15106]: 2017-09-07 11:27:44 140699007124032 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1) starting as process 15106 ...
Sep  7 09:27:44 debian mysqld[15106]: 2017-09-07 11:27:44 140699007124032 [Warning] Can't create test file /home/mysql/deb9.lower-test
Sep  7 09:27:44 debian mysqld[15106]: #007/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't change dir to '/home/mysql/' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
Sep  7 09:27:44 debian mysqld[15106]: 2017-09-07 11:27:44 140699007124032 [ERROR] Aborting
Sep  7 09:27:44 debian systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

As you may see, the error is *Permission denied*
some threads talks about *app armor* but this one is not running on processlist and I didn't touch anything about it.

```
grep -r maria /etc/apparmor
grep -r mysql /etc/apparmor
```

returns nothing.

I don't use SELINUX either ...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is not a good practice to store MySQL data under your `/home` directory. What is the specific thing you are trying to accomplish over here?

Comment: Is the `mysqld` service really starting with the `mysql` account or may this differ?

Comment: Maybe your filesystem is corrupted? What happens if you do something like this as root: "su mysql; touch /home/mysql/test" ?

Comment: @thomas by default it is the "mysql" user which is used  Tero: this is not the point here, i will use it as a lvm mount point ; wazoox: the vm is just launched so i don't think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `systemd` service file `mariadb.service` which has set

```
ProtectHome = true
```

by default. This setting prevents the service from accessing */home*, */root* and */run/user* directories.

So either you mount your `mysql` data to a different location or you set this feature to `false`.

To disable this feature, best would be to use `systemctl edit mariadb` which opens the editor defined in the environment variable `EDITOR`. Just put

```
[Service]
ProtectHome = false
```

in that editor. Save and close and an override file `/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/override.conf` will be created. After that a `systemctl daemon-reload` is needed to re-read the setting. Start your service.

Comment: works perfectly in my case! tnx for your answer Thomas